# How to corrupt a file without changing attributes for integrity testing?

Tags: windows, corruption

I'm trying to create a process for comparing two folders that should contain exactly the same files. Would like to be able to modify a file's content without changing the attributes as if the file was accidentally corrupted. Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You mean, without changing the last changed date? What kind of file?

Answer (score 1):

Use a disk editing tool to find some blocks for the file in question, and change their contents. Google a phrase like "disk hex editor" to find one. Now your file is corrupt, and you did not use the OS API calls which would have also updated the time stamps on the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell's `Get-FileHash` function.  It will compute the hash based on the contents of the file, not the time stamps.  Then you just compare the hash of `FileA` to `FileB`.  If the contents are the same then they should be the same hash.    This way you don't have to worry about edited the file to be different and comparing time stamp data.

Source:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/6/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash

> The **Get-FileHash** cmdlet computes the hash value for a file by using a
>   specified hash algorithm. **A hash value is a unique value that
>   corresponds to the content of the file. Rather than identifying the
>   contents of a file by its file name, extension, or other designation,
>   a hash assigns a unique value to the contents of a file.** File names
>   and extensions can be changed without altering the content of the
>   file, and without changing the hash value. Similarly, the file's
>   content can be changed without changing the name or extension.
>   However, changing even a single character in the contents of a file
>   changes the hash value of the file.
>
> The purpose of hash values is to provide a cryptographically-secure
>   way to verify that the contents of a file have not been changed. While
>   some hash algorithms, including MD5 and SHA1, are no longer considered
>   secure against attack, the goal of a secure hash algorithm is to
>   render it impossible to change the contents of a file-either by
>   accident, or by malicious or unauthorized attempt-and maintain the
>   same hash value. You can also use hash values to determine if two
>   different files have exactly the same content. If the hash values of
>   two files are identical, the contents of the files are also identical.
>
> By default, the Get-FileHash cmdlet uses the SHA256 algorithm,
>   although any hash algorithm that is supported by the target operating
>   system can be used.